# Create a Join leaving one row for any possible duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 2 tables that looks like this

[image]

How can I call the same column wihout duplicating it

TYSM for help

Comment: USe left join i guess

Comment: What column is expected on output third position?

Comment: 1st column of Table 1

Comment: Next time please paste tables as text. As to the problem: I wouldn't do such display things with SQL, but in your GUI layer instead (PHP/HTML table, C# grid, whatever).

Comment: Table1 is irrelevant here, by the way. All data you want to show is available in Table2.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below mentioned Query:

select distinct t2.data,t1.key,t1.data from t1.table1 JOIN table as t2 ON t1.key = t2.key

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a row number using a variable to t2 then join to t1 supressing the output of the t1.key.
for example

```
drop table if exists t1,t2;
create table t1 (id int);
create table t2 (id int, name varchar(2));

insert into t1 values(1),(2),(3),(4);
insert into t2 values(1,'s1'),(1,'s2'),(2,'s3'),(3,'s4'),(4,'s5');

select s.id, s.name,
         case when s.rn = 1 then s.rn
         else ''
         end as something
from t1
join
(
select t2.id,t2.name,
         if(t2.id <> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
         @p:=t2.id
from    t2,(select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
) s on t1.id = s.id
order by t1.id, s.name
```

Result

```
+------+------+-----------+
| id   | name | something |
+------+------+-----------+
|    1 | s1   | 1         |
|    1 | s2   |           |
|    2 | s3   | 1         |
|    3 | s4   | 1         |
|    4 | s5   | 1         |
+------+------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```